# google cloud DNS not proagating

Tags: dns, setup, cloud

I have gone over and over my set up and my site is still not working. Please take a look and see what you see wrong with this picture. Google Cloud DNS migrating from Google Domains. I tried to switch it back to domains and the site still didn't work. [image: DNS Config]

So I reset everything making a custom network. It looks like this but still not working:

[image: Google cloud DNS Zone record]

[image: Google cloud instance]

[image: Google cloud instance]

[image: Google cloud instance]

[image: Network]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the A record for `postaprayer.org` is correct (35.225.231.189) and that the server at that IP address is correctly hosting your website then your CNAMES are wrong.

You can’t put a URL in a CNAME. A CNAME record is an alias for another **domain** not a redirect to another URL.

The only CNAME that is formatted correctly is for `www.postaprayer.org` which is set as an alias for `postaprayer.org`.

You cannot use `HTTPS://` and you cannot include paths (I.e. `/prayer-group.html`) in your CNAMES.

Redirects have to be done by your web server not by DNS.

I’ve checked your public DNS record for `postaprayer.org` and it *correctly* comes back as 35.225.231.189. So if it isn’t your improper CNAME records then you are either using the wrong IP address or the server at that IP address is not correctly configured. Either way, it’s not a DNS issue then.

Comment: So I reset up the Google instance and dns and here is what it is looking like: